# Titanium doubletap and singletap event handler

Tags: javascript, android, click, titanium

I need to use both the '`singletap`' and '`doubletap`' events on a UI control, with each event triggering a different process. It works fine on Android. However, a '`doubletap`' event fires the '`singletap`' event as well as its own on mobileweb.

I also used `click` and `dblclick` but it is the same thing.

I'm wondering if you have workarounds for this issue.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var isDblclick = false;

view.addEventListener('dblclick',function(e){
    isDblclick = true;
    Ti.API.info("dblclick");
});

view.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    setTimeout(function(e){
            if(isDblclick == true){
                isDblclick = false;
                return;
            }
            Ti.API.info("click");
    },250);
});
```